# How many monomials appear in the polynomial $\prod_{i<j} (-1+x_i+x_j+x_i x_j)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, quadratics

Let $n$ be a positive integer. How many monomials appear with non-zero coefficients in the expansion of the polynomial

$$p(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\prod_{i<j} (-1+x_i+x_j+x_i x_j)\in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$$

in the monomial basis?

Comment: Have you tried small values of $n$ such as $n=1,n=2,n=3$? What did you get?

Comment: n=1: 0. n=2: 4. n=3: 21.

Comment: I get $(1,4,21,256,2885,44736,817509,16777216)$. When $n=1,2,4,8$ it is a power of $2$. Perhaps this helps. Note: $p(x_1) = 1$ is an empty product.